# How to using OpenStreetMap library on GitHub

Tags: android, android-studio

I am a beginner in Android, and I need to import [OpenStreetMap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenStreetMap) in my application. I have not found a way to do it. This is the library that I need: [link](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack)

The library has a tutorial, but I couldn't do it yet.

Answer (score 2):

First of all go to: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid

Here's an official repository of OpenStreetMap for Android. Add this to bookmark, as you would find nice `wiki` documentation and similar `issues` to future yours.

### Pre-requirements

Go to your `build.gradle` file and add these dependencies:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:5.4.1:release@aar'
}
```

You can always download it manually from [here](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/releases) and add to `assets` folder of your project.

> PROTIP: Set your `targetSdkVersion` to `22` for now to avoid problems
>   with runtime permissions on Android version 6.0 and higher.

Go to your `AndroidManifest.xml` and add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Now create your layout for your fisrst app

### Hello world example

Create a `"src/main/res/layouts/main.xml"` layout like this one. With `Android Studio`, it probably created one already called. The default is `"src/main/res/layouts/activity_main.xml"`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <org.osmdroid.views.MapView android:id="@+id/map"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Create or open existing the main activity (`MainActivity.java`):

```
import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.TileSourceFactory;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Important! Set your user agent to prevent getting banned from the OSM servers
    org.osmdroid.tileprovider.constants.OpenStreetMapTileProviderConstants.setUserAgentValue(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);

        MapView map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
        map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
    }
}
```

And that's enough to give it a try and see the world map.

Add default zoom buttons and ability to zoom with 2 fingers (multi-touch):

```
map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
map.setMultiTouchControls(true);
```

To move the map on a default view point, you need access to the map controller:

```
    IMapController mapController = map.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(9);
    GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(48.8583, 2.2944);
    mapController.setCenter(startPoint);
```

That's it. If you wish more, check: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-use-the-osmdroid-library#advanced-tutorial

I hope it will help.

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt, OsmDroid isn't "an official repository of OpenStreetMap for Android".  Many apps and libraries exist that allow people to work with OSM data in some way, but none of them are "official repositories of OpenStreetMap".  Of course, lots of people use OsmDroid and find it useful - but one thing that can confusion is the abstraction of the tile layers from the user, meaning they may be tempted to ignore https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/tiles/ and hit problems as a result.